# How to add textbox on a slide depending on what layout was used

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto, office-addins

The situation is as follows:
I have a presentation that contains 50 layouts. They can be divided into 3 types: one has no title, the other has a title at the bottom of the slide, and the third has a title on the top. I prepared PPT Addin (VSTO in C#) that adds textbox (with a specific format) on each slide:

```
using System;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TitleAddin
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.PresentationNewSlide +=
                new PowerPoint.EApplication_PresentationNewSlideEventHandler(
                    Application_PresentationNewSlide);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        void Application_PresentationNewSlide(PowerPoint.Slide Sld)
        {
            PowerPoint.Shape textBox = Sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(
                Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 21, 19, 900, 100);

            PowerPoint.TextRange dash = textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("— \n");
            PowerPoint.TextRange title = textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("Title \n");
            PowerPoint.TextRange subtitle = textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("Subtitle");

            dash.Font.Name = "Calibri";
            dash.Font.Size = 24;
            dash.Font.Bold = Office.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
            dash.Font.Color.RGB = Color.FromArgb(15,0,255).ToArgb();

            title.Font.Name = "Calibri";
            title.Font.Size = 24;
            title.Font.Bold = Office.MsoTriState.msoCTrue;
            title.Font.Color.RGB = Color.FromArgb(0,0,0).ToArgb();

            subtitle.Font.Name = "Calibri Light";
            subtitle.Font.Size = 24;
            subtitle.Font.Bold = Office.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
            subtitle.Font.Color.RGB = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0).ToArgb();
        }
```

The problem is:
I do not know how to recognise which layout is used by a slide. I thought that I can add an invisible shape on a layout and use its ID but shapes added to layouts are not present in the xml code of slides. The script should add specific text depending on which layout has been selected (these 3 types of layouts that I mentioned).

Note:
The important thing is that I don't want to add placeholders on specific layouts, but plain textbox on a slide, but depending on the layout it is based on. Something like: when I click "add new slide" and choose layout2 then it adds textbox1, when I choose layout5 it adds textbox2 etc.

Can you help me to find the solution or point me to the PPT objects that I should use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a VBA guy, you'll have to look up the C# equivalent. This code is not specific to solving your problem, but shows how to find the layout name and take actions on the slide based on that name:

```
Dim objSlide As Slide, LayoutIndex as Integer

For Each objSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    If objSlide.Design.Index = 1 Then 'Ignore slides based on other masters
        LayoutIndex(objSlide.SlideIndex) = objSlide.CustomLayout.Index 'Index is not absolute, but relative to slide master
    End If
    Select Case objSlide.CustomLayout.Name
        Case "Text Page", "Text Page No Bullets", "Text Page - Two Columns"
            For Each objShape In objSlide.Shapes    'Move subtitles to Title placeholders
                If objShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                    If objShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody And objShape.Top > 25 And objShape.Top < 70 _
                    And objShape.HasTextFrame And objShape.TextFrame2.HasText Then
                       'Do stuff here
                    End If
                End If
           Next objShape
     End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Changing VBA to C # is not easy for me so it will take me a little longer :)

Comment: There are sites that convert between VB and C#. Though I posted VBA, the VB syntax is similar. It's worth trying a couple of coversions to see if they get you at least partway there.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @John Korchok's answer, the only way of getting a slide's layout information is indeed only by knowing its name.

Assuming you want the name of the first slide in an open presentation, C# syntax would be:

```
var layoutName = presentation.Slides[1].CustomLayout.Name;
```

Then you can get the custom layout by its name from the slide master:

```
var layout = (from CustomLayout cl in slideMaster.CustomLayouts
                    where cl.MatchingName.Equals(layoutName)
                    select cl).FirstOrDefault();
```